# multiple model files or multiple apps?

Tags: django, django-models, django-apps

hello all i am building a project in django, and i am in doubt for some things and it would be great if you guys give me a good explanation about this issue.

i am planning to build a project which will work with DRF(Django Rest Framework) API. And the project is big so is it better:
 to separate models into subfolders: 
                                      models.py
                                      /submodels
                                         models1.py
                                         models2.py

or to create multiple apps like : 
       /Users
       /Campaigns
       /Billing
       /Statistics

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I personnaly would have make multiple apps if the API you are making will be consume by multiple applications.

Otherwise you can just make different models, so your project will be easier to manage and deploy.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest also the multiple apps approach (not doing submodels), i recently had experience with Django Rest Framework and its far easier keep everything separated by apps and define the views accordingly for the nested URLs.